# How can I perform a jOOQ update where the value assignment depends on the value of another column of the same row?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Using Postgres 14.5 (and jOOQ 3.17.6), assume the following `options` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE options (
  letter       uuid  NOT NULL,
  is_selected  bool  NULL,
);
```

...with data:

```
| letter | is_selected |
| A      | (null)      |
| B      | (null)      |
| C      | (null)      |
| ...    | (null)      |
```

How can I write an update to indicate that `B` was selected and the other values were not?

I tried a few things:

```
jooq
  .update(OPTIONS)
  .set(OPTIONS.IS_SELECTED, OPTIONS.LETTER == val("B")) <-- this didn't work because I
                                                            think this a memory address
                                                            comparison

  .set(OPTIONS.IS_SELECTED, OPTIONS.LETTER.equal(val("B"))) <-- this doesn't compile

  .execute()
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` definition for your table?

Comment: @LukasEder Hi Lukas - I've updated the question with those details. In reality, the "letter" column is a UUID, but I assume this detail isn't all that relevant to the whatever the solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from jOOQ 3.17 and [#11969](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11969), this compiles just fine, assuming your `BOOL` column is really a `BOOLEAN`:

```java
.set(OPTIONS.IS_SELECTED, OPTIONS.LETTER.equal(val("B")))
```

The reasons is that with [#11969](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11969), `Condition` is now a subtype of `Field<Boolean>`, which is what's expected here. Prior to jOOQ 3.17, you can always wrap a `Condition` in a `Field<Boolean>` explicitly, using [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Condition))

```java
.set(OPTIONS.IS_SELECTED, field(OPTIONS.LETTER.equal(val("B"))))
```

[See also this section of the manual about boolean columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/boolean-column/)

Comment: Using `OPTIONS.LETTER.equal(val("B"))`, my IDE shows a compilation error indicating no matching functions can be found. However, wrapping that expression in a `Field` as you mentioned does indeed work as desired. I'm using jOOQ 3.17.6, btw.

Comment: @homerman: I cannot reproduce such a compilation error with 3.17.12 or later